# Jump to immediate selection mode Vertex, Edge, Face addon for 2.8

Tags: scripting, add-on, customization

I use this addon to jump straight to cycle select between vertex, edges and faces on 2.79, instead of selecting the object, tab, edit mode, selection filter and (vertex).
But what do I need to change to upgrade it for 2.8?
Please help.
Thanks.

```
bl_info = {
'name': 'Direct Jump Selection',
'author': '-',
'version': (0, 0, 2),
'blender': (2, 80, 0),
'location': 'Blender'
'description': 'Enter edit mode and cycle selection type to face/vertex/edge',
'wiki_url': '',
'tracker_url': '',
'category': 'Object'}

import bpy

class EditSelectOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.edit_face_select'
    bl_label = 'Enter edit mode and set face selection.'

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.object.mode != 'EDIT':
            # if we aren't in edit mode goto edit and set face select
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=True)
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        else:
            # if we are editing cycle through selection modes
            sel_mode = context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode
            if sel_mode[0]: # vertex
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
            elif sel_mode[1]: # edge
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='FACE')
            else: # face
                bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(EditSelectOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EditSelectOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Works for fine for me if I add the missing comma behind `'location': 'Blender'`. Are you having a particular problem? The operator doesn't follow the naming convention, but that's all that I've noticed. BTW the industry compatible keymap has shortcuts for this on `1`,`2` and `3` keys.

Comment: yeah, you still have to go to edit mode to get "1", "2", "3" working. Not an immediate jump.
You mention it is working on your side? did you assigned a particular shortcut? I assigned it onto "4" but nothing is happening.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Yes, I do know. Too many keys. This is why I thought maybe this addon could solve immediate jump from object context. If you hover my profile pic on the answer you get insights to what I do ;)

Comment: Alright, you'd have to press TAB and 1, 2 or 3. I was just mentioning it in case you didn't know. It works for me, `4` is already assigned to other shortcuts though.

Comment: Assigning it to a shortcut that is unused, something like SHIFT+ALT+O, works fine.

Comment: HI. yes. "4" was assigned to "hide layer 4". Uncheck it and "4" shortcut works like magic. Thank you for detecting the ",". What a thing!

Comment: An IDE can help with that. Alternatively you can use the scripting workspace in 2.8, with the improved text editor. Makes add-on development and testing a lot quicker.